# Fitting GLMs on overlapping subsets of data

Tags: r, optimization, data.table, glm

I need to fit glms to various overlapping subsets of the same large data set (~7M rows) and then to save these model objects somewhere, so I'm looking to find the fastest way to do this.

I'm fairly new to the whole data.table aspect of R, but I thought using data.tables instead of data.frames should at least improve the filtering aspect.

However, given that the subsets I need to fit models to are overlapping, I can't just use the "by" argument on the data.table.

My data looks something like this:

```
IndepVar DepVar Flag1 Flag2 Flag3
1        14     G     B     G
0        21     B     B     G
1        19     G     G     B
etc.
```

Basically, for each possible combination of flags, I need to filter the "G" flags on the data and fit a glm.
i.e. I'll need to fit models for:
All data, data with Flag1 = "G", data with Flag2 = "G",data with Flag1 and Flag2 = "G", data with Flag3 = "G" etc.

So naturally the subsets overlap. And this would potentially need doing with larger data sets, with far more than 3 flags to look at.

The "quickest" way I could think of, based on my limited knowledge, would be something like:

```
#DT exists as data.table
allConditions <-c(parse(text="Flag1==\"G\""),parse(text="Flag2==\"G\""),...)
getGlm <- function(condition, dataTable){
    glmModel <- dataTable[eval(condition),glm(IndepVar~DepVar,data=.SD)]
    save(...)
}
lapply(X=conditions,FUN=getGlm,dataTable=DT)
```

In other words, wrapping the Glm logic in a function that takes in a "condition", then calling lapply on all explicitly defined combinations of flags.

But this still takes several minutes. Is there much room for improvement here, or am I somewhat limited by the nature of calling glm on numerous different subsets of the data?

Apologies if any of this is convoluted and unclear, but any help in optimising would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe run that `lapply` on multiple cores? depending on your OS, there are several packages you could use (just search for "r parallel lapply")

Answer (score 1):

So you need to save the whole `glm` object for every model? I don't know if there's a better way than using `lapply`, then.

Here's some random data:

```
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(I=rnorm(1e3), D=rnorm(1e3), F1=sample(c('G', 'B'), 1e3, replace=T), F2=sample(c('G', 'B'), 1e3, replace=T),F3=sample(c('G', 'B'), 1
e3, replace=T))
DT
                I           D F1 F2 F3
   1: -0.56047565 -0.99579872  G  G  G
   2: -0.23017749 -1.03995504  B  B  G
   3:  1.55870831 -0.01798024  B  B  G
   4:  0.07050839 -0.13217513  B  B  B
   5:  0.12928774 -2.54934277  G  G  G
  ---                                 
 996: -0.08997520  0.07664366  G  B  G
 997:  1.07051604  0.25516476  B  B  G
 998: -1.35110039  0.27744682  G  B  G
 999: -0.52261670  0.53685602  B  B  B
1000: -0.24919068 -0.46048557  G  B  B
```

Then create a column indicating the "group" (i.e., the combos of flags):

```
DT[, group := interaction(F1, F2, F3)]
DT
                I           D F1 F2 F3 group
   1: -0.56047565 -0.99579872  G  G  G G.G.G
   2: -0.23017749 -1.03995504  B  B  G B.B.G
   3:  1.55870831 -0.01798024  B  B  G B.B.G
   4:  0.07050839 -0.13217513  B  B  B B.B.B
   5:  0.12928774 -2.54934277  G  G  G G.G.G
  ---                                       
 996: -0.08997520  0.07664366  G  B  G G.B.G
 997:  1.07051604  0.25516476  B  B  G B.B.G
 998: -1.35110039  0.27744682  G  B  G G.B.G
 999: -0.52261670  0.53685602  B  B  B B.B.B
1000: -0.24919068 -0.46048557  G  B  B G.B.B
```

Now we can use `lapply` and save the objects:

```
myLevels <- DT[, unique(as.numeric(group))]
myGLMs <- lapply(myLevels, function(x) DT[as.numeric(group) == x, glm(I ~ D)])
str(myGLMs, max=1)
List of 8
 $ :List of 30
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "glm" "lm"
 $ :List of 30
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "glm" "lm"
 $ :List of 30
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "glm" "lm"
 $ :List of 30
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "glm" "lm"
 $ :List of 30
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "glm" "lm"
 $ :List of 30
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "glm" "lm"
 $ :List of 30
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "glm" "lm"
 $ :List of 30
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "glm" "lm"
```

On my system, with `1e6` rows and 3 flags, it took under `2` seconds. Increasing to 4 flags, it took the same amount of time. Increasing to 6 flags, it took a little over `2` seconds.

When I increased to `1e7` rows, 6 flags, it took `22` seconds (calculating all the interactions took just under `5` seconds).